# Run Test From TestNg File Via jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

I Want to run one test choosen  from testng file in jenkins via command shell  in EXECUTE SCRIPT SHELL JENKINS as:

```
   #!/bin/bash
   args=("$@")

   function goto
   {
   label=$1
   cmd=$(sed -n "/$label:/{:a;n;p;ba};" $0 | grep -v ':$')
   eval "$cmd"
   exit
   }

 export  projectLocation=E:\a\workspace_S2-2\FrameWorkAuto
  cd $projectLocation
  export  classpath=$projectLocation$\bin;projectLocation\lib\*
  java -cp "$projectLocation$\bin;projectLocation\lib\*" org.testng.TestNG - 
  testname "ManageAchat"  TestNG.xml
```

My test.xml file looks like below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
     <suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" 
     />
        <listener class-name="com.az.utilities.CustomListeners" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="Managetestss" group-by-instances="true">
        <classes>
        <class name="com.az.testsFlux.TNR_Vente_TestsVente" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="ManageAchat" group-by-instances="true">
        <classes>
        <class name="com.az.testsFlux.TNR_Achat_TestsAchat" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    </suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java -cp "$projectLocation$\bin;projectLocation\lib\*" org.testng.TestNG - 
  testname "ManageAchat"  TestNG.xml
```

When you use `-testname` you are telling TestNG to use the name called "ManageAchat" for the current test that is to be executed. This is overridden if there was a suite file found which defines a different name for the test via the `<test>` tag.

You should be using `-testnames`.

Quoting the documentation.

> A comma separated list of test names.Only tests defined in a `<test>`
>   tag matching one of these names will be run.

For more information, refer to the official documentation [here](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng).